# python and ipython seem to treat unicode characters differently

Tags: python, unicode, ipython, anaconda

I'm running python 2.7.12 from anaconda on windows 10. Included in the distro is ipython 5.1.0. I wrote a program to print certain columns of queried rows in a mysql database. The columns contain strings in unicode. When the program is run in python, an exception is thrown when a unicode character in one of the strings is first seen. The same program in ipython works, displaying all characters appropriately.

I've distilled the issue into a separate little program as follows:

```
name = u'O\u2019Connor'
try:
   print name
except:
   print "exception 1 thrown"

try:
   print u"{}".format(name)
except:
   print "exception 2 thrown"

try:
   print u"%s" % name
except:
   print 'exception 3 thrown'
```

When run using python, exceptions are thrown everytime. When run in ipython, all three print statements work. Obviously, there is a difference between the two versions in the way unicode is handled. What is the difference and what should I do so that my program will handle being run in either environment?

Comment: What are the exceptions?

Comment: Generated running python:  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: The problem is likely that python is trying to print using a codec that can't be converted from unicode while ipython is printing unicode directly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ipython is using a sane default output encoding (probably UTF-8 or UTF-16), while plain Python is using `cp437`, a limited one-byte-per-character ASCII superset that can't represent the whole Unicode range.

If you can control the command prompt, you can run `chcp 65001` before launching Python to make it use the "code page" for UTF-8 (which Python should pick up on). You might want to make this [the default for command prompts in general to avoid future problems](https://superuser.com/q/269818/556135).

Comment: I would **NOT RECOMMEND** setting the console to code page 65001, for Python or any other environment that uses the C standard library for IO. There are serious bugs in the console's handling of this code page (and other multi-byte code pages that are not explicitly supported as locale-default DBCS). You are likely to get mangled and repeated output, and missing input or hangs trying to use non-ASCII characters. Python 3.6 finally works around these problems, but until then the Windows command prompt is just broken and there's not a lot you can do about it.

Comment: As of IPython 5, IPython is using [win_unicode_console](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/win_unicode_console) to print unicode characters to the console. This is similar to the functionality integrated into Python 3.6.